# cordova run windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, exe, cordova

На cordova собрал проект.
Добавил две платформы: Android и Windows.

C Android реализацией я справился с помощью Android Studio (для меня оказалось по силам).

А вот как быть с версией для Windows?
Я запустил

*C:\Users\Entwickler\Cordova\Agent>cordova run windows*

Получил в ответ

*The following image was skipped because it has an unsupported size (undefinedxundefined): \www\img\web_hi_res_512.png
The following image was skipped because it has an unsupported size (undefinedxundefined): \www\img\Logo_F1_300dpi-02.png
Cannot read property 'targetProject' of null*

Visual Sdudio это какой-то монстр. НЕ нашёл пока нигде инструкции типа "вот создал проект в cordova, теперь установи вот такую вижуал студию, открой там вот эту папку из cordova, потом клацни там и сям и вот тебе exe"

Хотелось бы узнать как малой кровью получить exe-шник из cordova проекта?